# Big-O of Triple Nested Loop

Tags: java, big-o

What would the Time complexity (Big-O) of such an algorithm be

```
for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
    for (int j = 1; j < i; j++) {
        for (int k = 1; k < j; k++) {
            x++;
        }
    } 
}
```

Is it exponential?

Assuming the input is n

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) { // O(n) time complexity
    for (int j = 1; j < i; j++) { // O(n) time complexity
        for (int k = 1; k < j; k++) { // O(n) time complexity
            x++;
        }
    } 
}
```

The first loop does `n` number of computations. Your second loop continues to go until `i` reaches its condition, which is `n`, and `k` continues until `j`reaches its condition. Each loop is reaching the same condition, **`n`**

So, each loop has a time complexity of `O(n)`; because they are nested, you multiply each n, which results in a total time complexity of `O(n^3)`

Answer (score 0):

Each loop is `O(n)` so the overall is `O(n^3)`

Answer (score 0):

It will be 0(n^3) complexity as there are 3 loops with 0(n) complexity.
As  your number of loop increases, the time complexity of your method keeps on multiplying. So you have n loops in your program, then time complexity of your program will be 0(n^n). You can refer to this http://www.programmerinterview.com/index.php/data-structures/big-o-notation/ for more reference.

Comment: " As your number of loop increases, the time complexity of your method keeps on multiplying". not always, its worth mentioning that if loops are one after the other (not nested), it will still be O(n) no matter how many loops are there in a program that iterate 'n' times.